# Java Selenium Stuck in Login

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, automation, bots

I have a bot that running almost 1 year but lately it was stuck on login, it seems that the website is updated I'm not sure but I feel they put a bot detection features. When I make a "new tab" their is a warning says "Access denied ERROR 15. The request was blocked by our security service". But when I use a regular browser without the bot I was working fine. I really appreciated someone can help me out. Thanks!

```
public class Login {
    WebDriver driver;
    public Login() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Jars\\chromedriver.exe");        
        HashMap<String,Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
        chromePrefs.put("excludeSwitches", "enable-popup-blocking");    
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    
        //--------------------------------------------------
            options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
            options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
            options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", Collections.singletonList("enable-automation"));
            options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", null);             
            options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1080");
            options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36");
            options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        
        //------------------------------------------------
        
        try {
            
            driver.get("https://www.fpl.com/my-account/account-landing.html#cards");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            
            driver.findElement(By.id("emailOrUserId")).sendKeys("*******");
            driver.findElement(By.id("pwd")).sendKeys("********");
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(45, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.findElement(By.id("loginButton")).click();
            
        }catch(Exception ee) {ee.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Login();
    }
}
```

Comment: Probably they have implemented Antibot Services to stop scraping

Comment: Hi! thanks for your comment, is there anything I could do with this?